# Bootstrap addon causes page to scroll horizontally when on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input-group in my cshtml that includes a Bootstrap addon. The addon is prepended to the form-control. When on mobile, upon focus, the page scrolls horizontally to the right and the page's right margin can be seen. It scrolls off-page and stays there until the input box loses focus, then the page becomes centered again. How can I keep the page centered when the input receives focus?
My code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-left m-b-20" data-bind="validationElement: hin">
  <div>
    <span id="hin"
      data-bind="resourceText: 'Resource/File/Path/HIN', css: { error: hin.isModified() && !hin.isValid() }"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white;" id="basic-addon3"><b>C</b></span>

    <input id="hinInput" type="text" inputmode="numeric" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3"
      placeholder="HIN" data-bind="validationOptions: {insertMessages: false}"
      onfocus="document.getElementById('hin').classList.add('focused');"
      onblur="document.getElementById('hin').classList.remove('focused');" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>

  <p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationText: hin"></p>
</div>
```

I've tried setting the font size to 16px to prevent any zooming that might be happening but that didn't work. I tried including a sizing option for the input-group class, namely input-group-lg and input-group-sm but that didn't work. I tried putting padding and margins around the div container that contains the input-group which didn't work. I tried setting `overflow: hidden` to the input but that had no effect. In addition to a number or other methods, nothing so far has worked. The only method I have had success with is listening for a window.onscroll event when the input is focused and upon a scroll event being fired, immediately scroll back to the 0 position in the X plane, ie, `window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset)`. This centers the page but it has an undesirable screen 'shake' effect from the 2 successive scroll events. Why does this scrolling happen on mobile and are there any ways to avoid it?

Edit:
Here is the CSS for the input element's class

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9dce5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

More CSS for the input-group bootstrap class. Note that since this code is designated for a large company, the classes' attributes are spread across separate statements in the .css file and grouped by the attributes they share with other classes.

```
`.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.input-group[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.input-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.input-group .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 3;`
```

Comment: Can you please post the CSS for the affected input?

Comment: @Josh I've posted the css for the input's element's class. Let me know if there is another class you would like to see

Comment: probably you have a `.row` inside other `.row` without a container, you can simply solve by adding `overflow-x:hidden` to body and to html  `html,body{`overflow-x:hidden}`

Comment: Can you also post the CSS for `#hinInput` and `div.input-group` ?

Comment: @Sim1-81 this is a partial view and doesn't have any `body` or `html` tags. Nonetheless I added the tags to the top and included `style="overflow-x:hidden"` in them both but that didn't work. This div is currently nested inside one .row and another .col-xs-12 container

Comment: @Josh I've included that css now. There is no css for the `#hinInput` since it's just an id for the `form-control` input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This div was nested in another div with css `class=row`. Once I inserted `style="max-width:100%"` in that parent div, the issue was solved.